# Using the result of summarise (dplyr) to mutate the original dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, posixct, lubridate

I have a rather big dataframe with a column of POSIXct datetimes (~10yr of hourly data). I would flag all the rows in which the day falls in a Daylight saving period. For example if the Daylight shift starts on '2000-04-02 03:00:00' (DOY=93) i would like that the two previous hours of DOY=93 could be flagged.
Although I am a newbie of dplyr I would use this package as much as possible and avoid *for-loops* as much as possible

For example:

```
library(lubridate)
sd = ymd('2000-01-01',tz="America/Denver")
ed = ymd('2005-12-31',tz="America/Denver")
span = data.frame(date=seq(from=sd,to=ed, by="hour"))
span$YEAR = year(span$date)
span$DOY = yday(span$date)
span$DLS = dst(span$date)
```

To find the different days of the year in which the daylight saving is applied I use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
limits = span %.% group_by(YEAR) %.% summarise(minDOY=min(DOY[DLS]),maxDOY=max(DOY[DLS]))
```

That gives

```
      YEAR minDOY maxDOY
    1 2000     93    303
    2 2001     91    301
    3 2002     97    300
    4 2003     96    299
    5 2004     95    305
    6 2005     93    303
```

Now I would 'pipe' the above results in the *span* dataframe without using a inefficient *for-loop*.

### SOLUTION 1

with the help of @aosmith the problem can be tackled with just two commands (and avoiding the inner_join as in 'solution 2'):

```
 limits = span %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% mutate(minDOY=min(DOY[DLS]),maxDOY=max(DOY[DLS]),CHECK=FALSE)

 limits$CHECK[(limits2$DOY >= limits$minDOY) & (limits$DOY <= limits$maxDOY) ] = TRUE
```

### SOLUTION 2

With the help of @beetroot and @matthew-plourde, the problem has been solved:
an inner-join between was missing:

```
limits = span %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(minDOY=min(DOY[DLS]),maxDOY=max(DOY[DLS])) %>% inner_join(span, by='YEAR')
```

Then I just added a new column (CHECK) to fill with the right values for the Daylight-savings days

```
limits$CHECK = FALSE
limits$CHECK[(limits$DOY >= limits$minDOY) & (limits$DOY <= limits$maxDOY) ] = TRUE
```

Comment: So you want two new columns in span with minDOY and maxDOY and their values repeated for each row and respective years? That could probably done with left_join but can't test without example data.

Comment: Thank you @beetroot for the hint. I will try it now! For the example data... the code above does not work for you?

Comment: Ah I just don't have lubridate installed and am too lazy to do so for testing this right now ;)

Comment: No problem, beetroot! All has been solved with your help and with the help of matthew-plourde. And now I have a new tool thanks to oropendola. See the code above.

Comment: Adding new columns to an existing dataset seems like a job for `mutate` instead of `summarise` with joining.

Comment: yes, @aosmith... but the column to add contains a calculculation that can be accomplished (so far as I know) with the result of a joined summarise.

Comment: @Fabio Have you tried using `mutate(minDOY = min(DOY[DLS]), maxDOY = max(DOY[DLS]))` in place of where you use `summarise` in your original code?  That adds columns of group specific values to the original dataset, which is what it looks like you were trying to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @beetroot points out in the comments, you can accomplish this with a join:

```
limits = span %>% 
   group_by(YEAR) %>% 
   summarise(minDOY=min(DOY[DLS]),maxDOY=max(DOY[DLS])) %>%
   inner_join(span, by='YEAR')
#    YEAR minDOY maxDOY                date DOY   DLS
# 1  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 00:00:00   1 FALSE
# 2  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 01:00:00   1 FALSE
# 3  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 02:00:00   1 FALSE
# 4  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 03:00:00   1 FALSE
# 5  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 04:00:00   1 FALSE
# 6  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 05:00:00   1 FALSE
# 7  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 06:00:00   1 FALSE
# 8  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 07:00:00   1 FALSE
# 9  2000     93    303 2000-01-01 08:00:00   1 FALSE
# 10 2000     93    303 2000-01-01 09:00:00   1 FALSE
```

Comment: The join works as an intermediate step to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 4):

dplyr is a great tool, but in this case I'm not sure it's the best for the job.  This accomplishes your task:

```
span$CHECK <- ave(dst(span$date), as.Date(span$date, tz = tz(span$date)), FUN = any)
```

I think `ave` is a terrible name for this function, but if you can remember it exists, it's often quite useful when you want to join a summary back to the data.frame it came from.

Comment: well... like often, in R there is always room for learning new functions and new tricks. I Never used the *ave* function before. I will try it immediately!

Comment: This doesn't give the same results as `CHECK` in the OP.  You need to group by both `YEAR` and `DOY`.  I like your use of `any`, which makes the creation of `CHECK` so simple.  I think the dplyr equivalent is `span %>% group_by(YEAR, DOY) %>% mutate(CHECK = any(DLS))`

Comment: Thanks @aosmith, that was a bug.  I fixed the issue and made it so that `CHECK` could be calculated in one line using only `span$date`.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to get the job done, as suggested by @aosmith, is.

```
limits = span %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% mutate(minDOY=min(DOY[DLS]),maxDOY=max(DOY[DLS]),CHECK=FALSE)

limits$CHECK[(limits2$DOY >= limits$minDOY) & (limits$DOY <= limits$maxDOY) ] = TRUE
```

The use of the ave function is a good choice, but I personally prefer to stick to the 'dplyr' package.